# String.Format with NumberGroupSeparator outputting 0xa0 not comma

Tags: c#

I'm seeing strange results when doing a string.Format( "C" );

E.g.

```
    double val = 123456.78;
    Console.WriteLine( val.ToString( "C" ) );
```

This prints the thousand separator as 0xa0 rather than a comma (0x2c).

I get the same result if I use `string.Format( "{0:0,0.00}", 1234567.12D );`

Here is the full output

```
R 123ÿ456,78
52333A333233
201230456C78
```

My regional settings are English (South African) and I'm getting the same result on multiple machines.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: `123456.78d.ToString("C", new CultureInfo("en-ZA"))` returns `"R 123 456,78"` on my machine.

Comment: 123456.78d.ToString("C", new CultureInfo("en-ZA"));

I get the same 0xa0 character with this too. How bizarre. I've check the NumberFormatInfo and it looks fine....

Comment: Maybe some weird encoding issue? How do you know it's a 0xa0 character?

Comment: I do a ToCharArray and then hex encode each char

Comment: Are you sure that the second and third line of the output are generated by the Console.WriteLine statement at the beginning of your post?

Comment: Oh, no the 2nd and third are generated by this code


    public static void HexString( string str )
    {
        string l = "";
        string x1 = "";
        string x2 = "";
        
        foreach( char c in str )
        {
            int i = (int)c;
            
            l += c.ToString();
            string x = string.Format( "{0:X2}", i );
            x1 += x[0];
            x2 += x[1];
        }
        
        Console.WriteLine( l );
        Console.WriteLine( x1 );
        Console.WriteLine( x2 );        
    }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this was already answered [Space in a .NET string returned by string.Format does not match space declared in source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1476068/space-in-a-net-string-returned-by-string-format-does-not-match-space-declared-in).

0xa0 is a NO-BREAK SPACE, thanks dtb